# Why does a ManyToMany relationship created in setUpTestData cause a duplicate key error?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing, django-unittest

**I am using postgreSQL 12.**

I have the following models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

...and the following `TestCase` classes:

```
class TestA(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        p = Publication.objects.create()

        for _ in range(5):
            m = Article.objects.create()
            m.publications.add(p)

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

class TestB(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print(Article.objects.all())
        for _ in range(5):
            a = Article.objects.create()
            print(a.pk)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)
```

When I run these tests independently, the tests pass. When I run them
together, I get the following error for the `setUpTestData` method under
`TestB`:

> psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "article_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Further trial and error has led me to discover that this error only occurs
when I include the `ManyToMany` relationship for `TestA`:

```
 m.publications.add(p)
```

The first `print()` statement shows an empty queryset, so the `tearDownClass`
method for `TestA` appears to have worked, however the `pk` of the first `Article` is `1`, which is odd as I thought because Postgres PKs are generated from  Sequence objects they should never roll back.

What is happening here?

- shouldnt the first `Article` pk for `TestB` start with `6`?
- Why does a duplicate error occur? How is this linked to the `ManyToMany`
  relationship and how can I fix this or debug it further?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?